# Continuously adding and removing to flow-layout panel win forms

Tags: c#, winforms, flowlayoutpanel

I have a c# win forms application which has a `flowLayoutPanel` in it.

I need to update all the children in this panel every second.

here is my current code which gets called in a system timer every 1 seconds:

```
   public void RefreshReceiversPage()
    {
        if (checkBox_enableReceivers.Checked)
        {
            var receivers = OutgoingReceiverManager.GetCopyOfActiveRecieverHolders();

            for (int i = 0; i < flowLayoutPanel_receivers.Controls.Count; i++)
            {
                var tmp = flowLayoutPanel_receivers.Controls[i];
                flowLayoutPanel_receivers.Controls[i].Dispose();
                tmp.Dispose();
            }
            flowLayoutPanel_receivers.Controls.Clear();

            foreach (var item in receivers.ToList())
            {
                var tmpUc = new ucReceiverItem(item);
                if (flowLayoutPanel_receivers != null)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        flowLayoutPanel_receivers.Controls.Add(tmpUc);
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                    }
                }
            }
            receivers = null;
        }            
    }
```

now this code works perfectly for about 2 minutes and then all of a sudden I start getting `error creating window handle` Hence the reason for my try catch in the code above.

But after this happens the pane view goes funny and I cant recover it without starting up the program again.

I have searched high and low and I cant seem to find anything on the exception being thrown?

All that I can think is that im maybe not disposing of object properly and that its running out of memory some where?

Does any one have any suggestions or solutions?

EDIT:

here is UCRecieverItem:

```
public partial class ucReceiverItem : UserControl
{
    public ucReceiverItem(ReceiverHolder item)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ConstructItem(item);
        item = null;
    }

    private void ConstructItem(ReceiverHolder item)
    {
        label_name.Text = item.ReceiverDb.Name;
        label_numberOfConnections.Text = item.ReceiverOutgoingConnectionManager.GetNumberOfConnections().ToString();
        label_mrFilters.Text = item.ReceiverDb.MrFilters;
        label_multipleConnections.Text = item.ReceiverDb.MultipleConnections.ToString();
        //
        int count = item.GetActiveBufferCount();
        int size = item.GetActiveBufferSize();
        //
        label_bufferCount.Text = count + @" / " + size;
        progressBar_buffer.Maximum = size;
        progressBar_buffer.Minimum = 0;
        progressBar_buffer.Value = count;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it would be interesting to investigate what happens in constructor and Dispose method of `ucReceiverItem`

Comment: I will post the ucReceiverItem class for you.

Comment: Not sure what the point of that tmp variable is, but that whole for-loop is problematic since you are deleting items from the list as the list is shrinking.  You should probably just have a `while flp.Controls.Count > 0` loop and always dispose the first control: `flp.Controls[0].Dispose();`.

Comment: The temp variable was taken from another post, which supposedly disposes of the items better than `flowLayoutPanel_receivers.Controls.Clear()`

Comment: `Controls.Clear()` does not dispose of the controls.  It was meant to just remove the controls from the collection, not destroy the objects in case you wanted to add them back into a collection later.   I would remove that line of code.

Comment: @LarsTech: I also thought that there is a problem with the shrinking list. But in fact the loop doesn't remove the controls from the panel. It disposes them but keeps them in the list in a disposed state. After that the `Clear` empties the list. For that reason I think that the problem is not at that place. I could imagine that anywhere in the lifecycle of the ReceiverItem there is created a native window which is not freed in dispose method.

Comment: @Fratyx That deleting loop is only deleting half of the controls.  The Clear() call cleans up the rest but isn't disposing the controls, so they still exist, and if this is happening every second, the OP has potentially a lot of controls still in existence.  My read on it.

Comment: @LarsTech: The loop doesn't delete anything. All controls remain in the list. They just change their state to disposed. All of them. After the loop the list has as many items as before but all entries are disposed. 'Clear' removes them from the list and allow them to be garbage collected.

Comment: @LarsTech: Sorry you are right. Didn't realize that the Dispose function seems to deregister from parent although the object still exists after disposing.

Comment: Please see edit, I have added the ucRecieverItem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code is a problem:

```
for (int i = 0; i < flowLayoutPanel_receivers.Controls.Count; i++)
{
  var tmp = flowLayoutPanel_receivers.Controls[i];
  flowLayoutPanel_receivers.Controls[i].Dispose();
  tmp.Dispose();
}
flowLayoutPanel_receivers.Controls.Clear();
```

It is only disposing *half* of the controls in the container.  The other half get removed by the `Controls.Clear();` call, but those controls do not get disposed — so they still exist and are using up memory.

Doing this every second compounds the problem: that's potentially a lot of controls.

The immediate work-around would be to properly dispose of the controls:

```
while (flowLayoutPanel_receivers.Controls.Count > 0) {
  flowLayoutPanel_receivers.Controls[0].Dispose();
}
```

After that, I would question the need to do this every second — seems like a harsh environment for a user to work in.

Comment: Thanks, Will give this a try and give feedback.